# Iterating over multiple nested JSON using Object.keys in JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following data:

```
const temp = {
    "_id" : "5def6486ff8d5a2b1e52fd5b",
    "data" : {
        "files" : [
            {
                "path" : "demo1.cpp",
                "lines" : [
                    {
                        "line" : 18,
                        "count" : 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "path" : "file2/demo2.cpp",
                "lines" : [
                    {
                        "line" : 9,
                        "count" : 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, I want to access the `path`, and `line` variable inside each of the `files`. I am still learning using JS and pretty new with Object.keys.

I have this: 
`Object.keys(temp.data.files).forEach(file => console.log(file));`

This simply prints 0 and 1. Where am I going wrong in this?

Comment: Object.keys expects an Object but you're passing an array, just remove that and directly do `temp.data.files.forEach(file => console.log(file));`

Comment: `temp.data.files.forEach(file => console.log(file.path, file.lines, file.lines[0].line))`

Comment: You are getting 0 and 1, because when you call Object.keys() with an array, it returns an array of the indices

Answer (score 0):

This is because `temp.data.files` is an array. [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is used to loop through `Object`.

Try this:

```js
 const temp = {
    "_id": "5def6486ff8d5a2b1e52fd5b",
    "data": {
      "files": [
        {
          "path": "demo1.cpp",
          "lines": [
            {
              "line": 18,
              "count": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "path": "file2/demo2.cpp",
          "lines": [
            {
              "line": 9,
              "count": 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  temp.data.files.forEach(file => console.log("path ", file.path, " lines ", file.lines));
```